# Android notification from web site

Tags: android

On my website I have a form to put posts on *wall* by logged in users.
I want the users to get notification in the Android app whenever a new post is posted.

Can anyone please suggest an idea for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally this is done using [Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/),
and in human language the thing you are trying to implement is called a *push notification*.

**UPDATE:**

[C2DM (Cloud to Device Messaging)](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) was officially deprecated on June 26, 2012, and will be shut down completely as of July 30, 2015. Existing [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) developers are encouraged to migrate to [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). See the [C2DM-to-GCM Migration document](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm.html) for more information.

**UPDATE 2:**

[GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) was officially deprecated on April 10, 2018, and will be shut down completely as of April 11, 2019. Existing [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) developers are encouraged to migrate to [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). See the [GCM-to-FCM Migration document](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) for more information.

Developers must use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for new development.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but application can connect to server and check if there exist any new content. Good luck

Comment: @Andrejs's answer seems like the correct one, mine isn't specific enough

Comment: Actually, I think that whether the 'correct' idea is to use C2DM - i.e. *push* - or your suggested method of *polling* a server actually depends on the requirements. If the application does not require 'instant' notifications, but it is sufficient for the application to be notified of new messages every, say, one hour, then I'd consider simply polling a server as you suggest. The need for more frequent polling leads to reduced battery life and expensive network access, which is where you need the extra complexity of push notifications, i.e. C2DM. So it depends on the OP's needs really.